# Finding a Palindrome Number Between A Given Range Using The Number Of Digits

Tags: java, loops, palindrome

so i have to write a program that will find all palindrome numbers between a given range. ***The program must use a numDigits() method that takes a int number and returns the number of digits of that int.***

A isPalindrome() method that will take a int number and will return a boolean true or false whether the number is a palindrome or not

I have a numDigit() method coded here:

```
public static int getNumDigits(int numCount, int END) 
{  

   //local variables 
   int numDigits;

     numDigits = 0;

       while(numCount <= END)
       { 
           numDigits = (int)(Math.log10(numCount)+1);

              if(num == 0) 
              { 
                   numDigits = 1;
              }

               numCount++;

       }//end of minor loop

      return numDigits;

}// numDigit Method
```

I do know how to find a palindrome in another way but the assignment is specific to this technique. ***How can I implement this numDigit() method into finding all palindrome numbers given between a range?***

Comment: As written your current implementation of `getNumDigits` will not compile.  I'd advise starting there.  Once it runs you may find it useful in implementing isPalindrome()

Comment: How can i use this method now to find all palindrome numbers between a range

Comment: i know i have to somehow loop it

Answer (score 1):

**You need to know the number of digits to find if the number is a palindrome as shown in this algorithm**:

1. Count the number of digits in the number.
2. If the number has an odd number of digits, remove the middle digit, making a number with an even number of digits.
3. Check if it is a palindrome by splitting it in half.

   ```
   public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {
   //convert number to string for easy processing
   String num = Integer.toString(number);

   // count number of digits in number
   int digitCount = numDigits(number);

   // if number has odd number of digit
   if (digitCount % 2 == 1) {
       // remove middle digit
       num = num.substring(0, Math.floorDiv(digitCount, 2)) + num.substring(Math.floorDiv(digitCount, 2) + 1);
       // since you removed a digit, the number of digits is one less
       digitCount = digitCount - 1;
   }

   // split number in half
   String half1 = num.substring(0, digitCount / 2);
   String half2 = num.substring(digitCount / 2);

   // check if two halves are same
   for (int i = 0, j = half2.length() - 1; i < half1.length() && j >= 0; i++, j--) {
       if(half1.charAt(i)!=half2.charAt(j)){
           return false;
       }
   }

   return true;
   }
   ```

Comment: if the isolating part that is difficult for me to figure out

Comment: What do you mean by the isolating part?